# 301 redirect a URL that has a specific query string value in it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect a few URLs that have specific query string values in them. I've found a bunch of examples that looks like they'd make sense but they just don't work for me.

Here's what I'm working with.

I need to redirect this URL..
http://www.example.com/QuickSearchForm/QuickSearchForm/Search/1?p=C

to..

http://www.example.com/find-your-home/communities

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=C [NC]
RewriteRule ^QuickSearchForm/QuickSearchForm/Search/1/?$ /find-your-home/communities? [L,NC,R=301]
```